# Express the sum $\sum_{1\gt}i\cdot j$ in elementary function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How to represent this sum $$\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}ij$$ as an elementary function?
I figured out that given sum might be written as $$n\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+(n-1)\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}+\cdots+3\frac{3\cdot2}{2}+2\frac{2\cdot1}{2}$$ but I can't get how to simplify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\sum_\limits{1\le i\le j\le n}ij=(1.2+1.3+\ldots+1.n)+(2.3+2.4+\ldots+2.n)+\ldots+(n-1)n$$
Then $$\sum_\limits{1\le i\le j\le n}ij=\sum_\limits{i=2}^n\sum_\limits{j=1}^{i-1}i.j=\sum_\limits{i=2}^ni.\frac{(i-1)(i)}{2}=\frac 12\sum_\limits{i=2}^n(i^3-i^2)=\frac 12\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(i^3-i^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$=\dfrac{(1+2+\cdots+n)^2-(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2))}2$$

as $$2ab=(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)$$